# How to see "View State" or development mode in inline visualforce page?

Tags: inline-visualforce, viewstate

I have two inline visualforce pages embedded in Account layout. I need to see the view state of the vf pages and tried to analyze the page performance and the resources it is consuming. How to see "view state" or development mode in inline visualforce page? Any suggestions please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices.

1. View the page directly. You can right click within the Visualforce page area and choose "open frame in new window" (most browsers), or simply type the address into your address bar (include an id parameter if necessary).
2. Make the frame larger. Adjust the size of the frame so the footer is visible. You can configure this on the layout itself. The footer is included when development mode is turned on, but if the frame is too small, you may not be able to see or interact with it.